# Get report of the gui application processes

Tags: x-server, wmctrl

I want to list main applications processes report in this format

```
ps -e -o pid,comm,pmem,pcpu,uname
```

To filter main GUI applications `wmctrl -pl` is the only way I can get processes ids.its great if `xlsclients` can be used. It contains the real list with names I want.

How can I combine them as single commands to get report as I want. (ps -p = xlsclients -p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often the case that in Unix you can chain commands together, and often times many commands are built specifically so that they'll work with the output generated by other commands.

Luckily you can take the output of `xlsclients` and parse it down so that it's just the name of the command. You can then pass this info to the `ps` command to get the output you're looking for:

```
$ xlsclients
dufresne  conky -c /home/slm/.conky/b.conf
dufresne  cinnamon-session
dufresne  cinnamon-settings-daemon
dufresne  csd-locate-pointer
dufresne  clipit

$ xlsclients | cut -d" " -f3 | paste - -s -d ','
conky,cinnamon-session,cinnamon-settings-daemon....
```

You can then give this list of process names to the `-C` switch of `ps`.

```
$ ps -o pid,comm,pmem,pcpu,uname \
    -C $(xlsclients | cut -d" " -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')
```

**NOTE:** We've removed the `-e` switch since we're now providing a list to `ps`.

#### Example

```
$ ps -o pid,comm,pmem,pcpu,uname \
    -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d" " -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" | head 
  PID COMMAND         %MEM %CPU USER
 1998 cinnamon-launch  0.2  0.0 slm
 2031 cinnamon         6.5  0.7 slm
16736 cinnamon-launch  0.3  0.0 slm
16738 cinnamon         6.1  2.7 slm
16994 cinnamon-sessio  0.2  0.0 slm
17231 cinnamon-settin  0.4  0.0 slm
17293 csd-locate-poin  0.2  0.0 slm
17331 nm-applet        0.3  0.0 slm
17339 clipit           0.2  0.1 slm
```

Comment: thanks, But how to get the sum of same command group, without repeat them. cinnamon %MEM => 6.5+6.1 = 12.6, %CPU => 0.7+2.7 = 3.4

Comment: ok, i fixed it from awk. ps -o pid,comm,pmem,pcpu,uname -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d" " -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "; print "PID COMMAND %MEM %CPU count"} NR!=1 {comm[$2]++;pid[$2]=$1;pid[$2]=$1;mem[$2]=mem[$2]+$3;cpu[$2]=cpu[$2]+$4}END{for (i in comm) printf("%d %s %5.2f %5.2f %d\n",pid[i],i,mem[i],cpu[i],comm[i])}'

Answer (score 0):

$ ps -o pid,comm,pmem,pcpu,uname \
    -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d" " -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" | head 
  PID COMMAND         %MEM %CPU USER
 1998 cinnamon-launch  0.2  0.0 slm
 2031 cinnamon         6.5  0.7 slm
16736 cinnamon-launch  0.3  0.0 slm
16738 cinnamon         6.1  2.7 slm
16994 cinnamon-sessio  0.2  0.0 slm
17231 cinnamon-settin  0.4  0.0 slm
17293 csd-locate-poin  0.2  0.0 slm
17331 nm-applet        0.3  0.0 slm
17339 clipit           0.2  0.1 slm