# How to list all running daemons?

Tags: services, daemon

From my question [Can Process id and session id of a daemon differ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175008/can-process-id-and-session-id-of-a-daemon-differ), it was clear that I cannot easily decide the features of a daemon. I have read in different articles and from different forums that `service --status-all` command can be used to list all the daemons in my system. But I do not think that the command is listing all daemons because `NetworkManager`, a daemon which is currently running in my `Ubuntu 14.04` system, is not listed by the command. Is there some command to list the running daemons or else is there some way to find the daemons from the `filesystem` itself?

Comment: Are you sure it's not listed? How are you checking? I can see it on my Debian. Note that the name is `network-manager`, not `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. Nothing related to the term network is listed. Also it lists `anacron` which is mentioned as not a daemon in its init script.

Comment: Anacron not being a daemon is more a question of semantics because it is not run constantly. It is still run as a service which is what you normally refer to as daemons. Please [edit] your question and i) tell us which Ubuntu you are running and ii) what exactly you mean by "daemon". What is your final objective here?

Comment: I suppose any service running in the background is a daemon. I mentioned `anacron` because it was said in `/etc/init.d/anacron` that it is not a daemon. My objective is to write a `C++` program to list all daemons running in my system. For that I need to know which files to parse to get the details.

Comment: Well, if you define daemons as services, `service --status-all` is what you need. Ubuntu seems to treat NetworkManager differently. I get both `networking` and `network-manager` in the output of `services --status-all` on Debian but only `networking` on Ubuntu. I think you need to define what exactly you mean by "daemon".

Comment: So isn't `daemon a service? Sorry to ask.. But I am new to Linux and from the information I obtained, I thought that daemons were services.

Comment: Yes they are, but you don't seem to like that definition :). If you accept that daemon==service, then `service --status-all` gives you everything you want. You seem to want more which is why I ask how _you_ define "daemon".

Comment: I happened to find in google that `NetworkManager` is a daemon and when I checked if it is running, it returned true. Then why dont `service --status-all` list it? Also I have a process named `rtkit-daemon` which is not listed by the command. Isn't it a daemon?

Comment: I suggest you post a different question asking what a daemon is.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The notion of *daemon* is attached to *processes*, not *files*. For this reason, there is no sense in "finding daemons on the filesystem". Just to make the notion a little clearer : a program is an executable file (visible in the output of `ls`) ; a process is an instance of that program (visible in the output of `ps`).

Now, if we use the information that I gave in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175008/can-process-id-and-session-id-of-a-daemon-differ), we could find running daemons by *searching for processes which run without a controlling terminal  attached to them*. This can be done quite easily with `ps`:

```
$ ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?
```

*The `tty` output field contains "?" when the process has no controlling terminal.*

The big problem here comes when your system runs a graphical environment. Since GUI programs (i.e. Chromium) are not attached to a terminal, they also appear in the output. On a standard system, where root does not run graphical programs, you could simply restrict the previous list to root's processes. This can be achieved using `ps`' `-U` switch.

```
$ ps -U0 -o 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?
```

Yet, two problems arise here:

- If root is running graphical programs, they will show up.
- Daemons running without root privileges won't. Note that daemons which start at boot time are usually running as root.

Basically, we would like to *display all programs without a controlling terminal, but not GUI programs*. Luckily for us, there is a program to list GUI processes : `xlsclients`! [This answer from slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147086/41892) tells us how to use it to list all GUI programs, but we'll have to reverse it, since we want to exclude them. This can be done using the `--deselect` switch.

First, we'll build a list of all GUI programs for which we have running processes. From the answer I just linked, this is done using...

```
$ xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ','
```

Now, `ps` has a `-C` switch which allows us to select by command name. We just got our command list, so let's inject it into the `ps` command line. Note that I'm using `--deselect` afterwards to reverse my selection.

```
$ ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --deselect
```

Now, we have a list of all non-GUI processes. Let's not forget our "no TTY attached" rule. For this, I'll add `-o tty,args` to the previous line in order to output the `tty` of each process (and its full command line) :

```
$ ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --deselect -o tty,args | grep ^?
```

The final `grep` captures all lines which begin with "?", that is, all processes without a controlling tty. And there you go! This final line gives you all non-GUI processes running without a controlling terminal. Note that you could still improve it, for instance, by [excluding kernel threads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78585/41892) (which aren't processes)...

```
$ ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --ppid 2 --pid 2 --deselect -o tty,args | grep ^?
```

... or by adding a few columns of information for you to read:

```
$ ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --ppid 2 --pid 2 --deselect -o tty,uid,pid,ppid,args | grep ^?
```

Comment: linux keeps many info on a virtual filesystem, procfs. so it is feasible "finding daemons on the filesystem" !!!

Answer (score 6):

With a modern system running [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (Debian based, Fedora, RedHat/CentOs, ...), the command `systemctl` is there to handle everything that is controlled by systemd.
So to get a list of services, you can do:

```
systemctl | grep daemon
```

**Edit 2022/10** :
To be more specific, `systemd` handles many things in the kernel, you can run `$ sudo systemctl -t help` to see.

To check for services, run `$ sudo systemctl --type=service` and grep for the one you want.

Comment: This is the correct, modern answer

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for the "old" sysv initd, you have to check if it is working on your distro.

Good demons have well written startup scripts in /etc/initd

When changing runlevel, how does init know the running daemons ?

It looks for their names in the directory

> /var/lock/subsys

So you can

> get the names list from there
>
> scan all the running processes and check if the name is inside the list: bingo !

To scan all the processes: list every subdirectory in

> /proc

If its name is digits, it is the pid of a running process.

For example, the status of the process  with pid 1234 is this file

> /proc/1234/status

Open it and get the first line, starts with "Name:"

See

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html
>
> https://linuxexplore.com/2014/03/19/use-of-subsystem-lock-files-in-init-script/

(sorry for the nasty formatting, I am writing from my cell phone...)